# Odd Android TabLayout Indicator Scrolling Bug

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, viewpagerindicator

I am using `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager` in Android. Whenever I run the code, the TabLayout Indicator is behaving oddly. Instead of auto-snapping to the next tab, it's acting like a horizontal scrollbar. So I have a TabLayout Indicator that's literally hanging between two tabs. And there is no error. Here is my code:

My `onCreate()` method:

```
val tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tl)
val viewPager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.vp)

viewPager.adapter = AmpPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

val icons = arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_hot_24dp, R.drawable.ic_person_24dp)
icons.forEachIndexed { index, i -> tabLayout.getTabAt(index)?.setIcon(i) }
```

My FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
class AmpPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    private val pages = arrayListOf(Fragment(), Fragment())
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = pages[position]
    override fun getCount(): Int = pages.size
}
```

First I thought I added too many tabs, but that isn't the case as my Pages Array List length is 2. **The Indicator works fine when I click on the tabs.**

What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the issue was that I was filling the `FragmentPagerAdapter` with the default Fragment class from Android, **which has no layout attached to it.** When I made my own fragment and inflated the layout, the TabLayout Indicator started working properly.

Note that the actual problem was that **there was no layout inflated.** And that's why filling in the default Fragment class was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
AmpPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
```

I was having the same issue using the `getSupportFragmentManager()`
As posted answer by @SynerFlow himself, that was the reason.
My solution was using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead.

Thank you